# Поймать клик и получить значение тега в динамически загружаемом контенте jquery

Tags: jquery

имею несколько блоков с разными id

```
<div class="p1">
  <div class="p2" id-post-answer="ХХХ">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ответить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

На странице подгружаются еще такие блоки с помощью ajax

Обработчик всего этого:

```
$(document).ready(function($)
  {
  $(".p1").each(function(index, element)
    {
    // если кликнули ответить
    $(element).find(".p2").click(function(e)
      {
      var id_post = $(element).find(".p2").attr("id-post-answer");
      console.log("click "+id_post);
      });
    });
  });
```

Не могу получить значение id-post-answer у подгружаемых динамически блоков. У загружаемых сразу значение получаю, а у подгружаемых нет. Не могу понять почему. Помогите люди добрые :)

Update: где тут должен быть $("body").on("click", - но блин. убей не пойму принцип работы в моем случае :(

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский нет

Comment: ДА!  не смотря на то, что в вопросе упоминается ajax - суть всё та же: динамически подгружаемый контент

Comment: @hibinyru, ответ на ваш вопрос находится в самом конце ответа, что добавил **Алексей**, почитайте про такую штуку, как [Делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), так же в статье [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) тоже об этом говорится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ожидалось, что кто-нибудь из добрых людей напишет:

```
  $("body").on("click", ".p2", function (e)
    {
    var id_post_answer = $(this).attr("id-post-answer");
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

иногда бывает тупишь на ровном месте...

Answer (score 0):

Событие клика навешивается на те элементы, которые существуют в момент навешивания. Иначе говоря, на подгруженные блоки это распространяться не будет. Поэтому вам необходимо после подгрузки вешать снова событие на подгруженные элементы

**UPD**: В комментариях под вопросом предложен хороший метод с навешиванием события на родительский блок. Внутри обработчика уже проверять через `event.target` какой конкретно элемент нажат.

Comment: походу там где-то должен быть $("body").on("click", но как и куда, понять не могу. До сих пор сложновато это направление